# TclError: invalid command name ".!eightqueens.!frame.!label" when configuring label background color

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am quite new to **tkinter(8.6)** and have some experience in **python(3.7.9)**.

I am making a program to solve the NQueens problem, the base code works and changes the values in the matrix, however when I **try to configure the label when calling the method from the solver.py file**, I get the error in the title. But if I call the method when testing the error does not appear.

Any ideas for a solution?

eightQueens.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

CELLCOUNT = 7

class eightQueens(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        
        self.master.title('Eight Queens Problem Solver')
        self.grid()
        self.boardCells = []
        self.makeBoard()
        self.initBoard(CELLCOUNT)
        self.place(CELLCOUNT)
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.mainloop()

    def makeBoard(self):
        background = tk.Frame(self, bg='#858282', width=600, height=600)
        background.grid(padx=(150,150),pady=(150,150))

        for row in range(CELLCOUNT):
            gridRow = [] 
            for col in range(CELLCOUNT):
                cell = tk.Label(background, text='', bg='#ffffff', justify=tk.CENTER, width=10, height=4)
                cell.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=1, pady=1)
                gridRow.append(cell)
            self.boardCells.append(gridRow)
    
    def initBoard(self, n):
        self.board = np.zeros((n**2), dtype='int').reshape((n,n))
    
    def place(self,n):
        board = self.board
        for row in range(n):
            for col in range(n):
                value = board[row][col]
                if value != 0:
                    self.boardCells[row][col].configure(bg='red')
        self.update_idletasks()
    

gameBoard = eightQueens()
```

solver.py

```
QUEEN = 1
N = 7
def placeSolution(board):
        print(board)  
        gameBoard.place(N)

def isSafe(board, row, col): 
  
    # Check this row on left side 
    for i in range(col): 
        if board[row][i] == QUEEN: 
            return False
  
    # Check upper diagonal on left side 
    for i, j in zip(range(row, -1, -1),  
                    range(col, -1, -1)): 
        if board[i][j] == QUEEN: 
            return False
  
    # Check lower diagonal on left side 
    for i, j in zip(range(row, N, 1),  
                    range(col, -1, -1)): 
        if board[i][j] == QUEEN: 
            return False
  
    return True
  
def solveNQUtil(board, col): 
    if col >= N: 
        return True

    for i in range(N): 
        if isSafe(board, i, col):  
            board[i][col] = QUEEN 
            if solveNQUtil(board, col + 1) == True: 
                return True
            board[i][col] = 0
    return False

def solve():
    board = gameBoard.board
    if (solveNQUtil(board, 0) == False):
        print("No Solution")
        return False  
    placeSolution(board)
    # gameBoard.place(N)
    return True  

solve()
```

Here is the error message:

```
 [[1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/***/Documents/GitHub/***/src/eightQueens/solver.py", line 129, in <module>
    solve()
  File "c:/Users/***/Documents/GitHub/***/src/eightQueens/solver.py", line 125, in solve
    placeSolution(board)
  File "c:/Users/***/Documents/GitHub/***/src/eightQueens/solver.py", line 68, in placeSolution
    gameBoard.place(N)
  File "c:\Users\***\Documents\GitHub\***\src\eightQueens\eightQueens.py", line 40, in place
    self.boardCells[row][col].configure(bg='red')
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!eightqueens.!frame.!label"
```

Comment: I think this error usually comes when you destroy the frame(`eightQueens`) and try to change it. And will the example work if we copy paste and run?

Comment: I have edited the code so you can try to replicate it, the error appears after i close the window, but the label doesnt change while the program is running as well

Comment: Not sure it is the problem, but you should change the name of the method that you called `place` in `GameBoard`; it is overriding `tk.Frame` `place`.

Comment: I changed the name of the method called ```place``` to "placeQueens" and the same error still occurs

Comment: What is `QUEEN` supposed to be?

Comment: ```QUEEN``` is just an int 1, to be placed into the array where a queen is placed, better to have a name for it than just a random 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `self.mainloop()` was in the incorrect place causing the GUI to create the board before any changes could be made, then calling the `place` method after the GUI was destroyed, hence causing the error.

It was fixed by moving the `self.mainloop()` to the solver.py file under calling

```
solve()
gameBoard.mainloop()
```